# How to paste static data in a new column on one worksheet for every new row added to a table on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, project

I am a novice in VBA and coding in general and am in the beginning stages of creating a project management tool. The process of using this tool begins with an employee entering a list of accounts that need to be opened. For each account there is a standardized list of tasks that need to be completed for that account to be officially be opened.

What I want is that for each new account that is added, the standardized list of tasks appear together on a separate sheet than where the accounts that need to be opened are.

What I am thinking of is using a loop such that for each new row that is added to the table of accounts that need to be opened, the standardized list of tasks is copied from a worksheet in the workbook to the worksheet containing all the standardized lists for all the accounts. This is code I have in the works. However, I could use help and direction.

```
Dim New_Markets As Range
Set New_Markets = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List of Markets").Range("A1:B104")

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SKAs").ListObjects("Table1").Range.Rows.Count

Dim SKAs As Range
Set SKAs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SKAs").Range("A1:E" & LastRow)

For Each Rows In SKAs
'I want to add a column of New_Markets to the sheet "Market to Open"
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a single row on one sheet (account number) to become multiple rows on another sheet (list of tasks). It can be done, but first consider columns. Could the tasks be columns instead of rows? You could type OK in a column to mean a task was completed. Alternatively you can make a single row look like multiple rows, if the list is only for reading or printing. To insert line breaks, type Alt+Enter. In a cell, type the first task, Alt+Enter, second task, Alt+Enter, and so on. If these workaround won't work, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer that I was looking for:

```
Sub Adding_New_SKAs()

Dim New_Markets As Range
Set New_Markets = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List of Markets").Range("A1:B104")

Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SKAs").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Dim i As Integer, Index As Integer

Index = 0

For i = 2 To LastRow
   New_Markets.Copy Sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(0, Index)
   Index = Index + 3
Next i

Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```